# Facebook URL Debugger giving errors, OG tags not in head error

Tags: facebook, meta

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chiploco.com%2Frazer-ouroboros-review-22725%2F

For some reason, the FB URL Debugger is saying that the meta tags are in body tag instead of head but from what I can see they are clearly in the head tag.

Can anyone see whats the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For some reason, the FB URL Debugger is saying that the meta tags are in body tag instead of head but from what I can see they are clearly in the head tag.

Nope, they are not.

The OG relevant `meta` tags are placed beginning on line #127 in your code – but on line #93 you have a `noscript` element containing a `div` element. Since a `div` element has no business being inside the `head` element, the `head` element is closed *implicitly* before that.

And that results, from a DOM view, in your `meta` elements being outside of the `head`.

Please *always* use the validator to check your HTML before asking this kind of question: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.chiploco.com/razer-ouroboros-review-22725/

As you can see, there are quite a few more issues that want to be fixed.